# How can I center a list within a list?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

I am trying to center a list of options within an enumerated list environment. Like so,

```
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Which of the following statements is true?
    \begin{center}
        \begin{enumerate} [I.]
            \item Statement the first.
            \item Statement the second.
            \item Statement the third.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{center}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The `center` environment does nothing, however. I have also tried embedding the `center` environment above in a `minipage`, but this also did nothing.

My goal is to make this like something you might see on the SATs, where the statements are centered but everything else is left-aligned. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

I have no idea what SATs look like but I suspect you want something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Which of the following statements is true?
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
        \begin{enumerate} [I.]
            \item Statement the first.
            \item Statement the second.
            \item Statement the third.
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Or in comments there is a suggestion that you meant the second example below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Which of the following statements is true?
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
        \begin{enumerate} [I.]
            \item Statement the first.
            \item Statement the second a bit longer.
            \item Statement the third.
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
  \end{enumerate}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Which of the following statements is true?
        \begin{enumerate} [I.]\centering
            \item Statement the first.
            \item Statement the second a bit longer.
            \item Statement the third.
        \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! But I guess that the OP wants all 3 items centered, not the whole block centered. Let's wait.

Comment: @Sigur you mean as in the updated answer? (ug:-)

Comment: Wow, I'm glad it was so simple. It totally makes sense that the 'minipage' environment should be centered; I'm embarrassed that I only tried it the other way around.  And for clarity, I desired your first example. That second example is good to know, too, though. I had no idea you could put commands immediately following the '\begin' command.  Anyway, thanks a ton, @DavidCarlisle!